# Image won't display when using session in .NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0

I am working with a session and I want to display image when choosing it from a gridview, so what I have two gridviews the first contain the rows from the database the second should contain the rows chosen from the first one the issue that I have is the first display image with no problem but the second won't show up any.

This is my code for the first one

```
foreach (CONTENT c in ls)
{
    string ext = Helper_GetExtensionFromMimeType(c.MimeType);
    c.TmpFilename = string.Format("~/Images/Contents/Content-{0}{1}", c.ContentID, ext);
}

gridview1.DataSource = ls;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

The code for the second one is (the session name is `panier`)

```
CONTENT dummy;
dummy = new CONTENT();
dummy.TmpFilename = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Images/Contents/Content-{0}{1}",
  c.ContentID, ext));
panier.Add(dummy);
gridview2.DataSource = panier;
gridview2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to the probleme and here it is if anyone is interested

i replace

```
     dummy.TmpFilename = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Images/Contents/Content-{0}{1}",c.ContentID, ext));
```

with

```
  dummy.TmpFilename =string.Format("~/Images/Contents/Content-{0}{1}",c.ContentID, ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to determine what the issue exactly is without seeing your view code.

Anyway, make sure the image indeed exists in the generated location.

Place a breakpoint after the line `dummy.TmpFilename` and ensure the link is indeed formatted with the correct `c.ContentID` and `ext`, then copy the link to the browser making sure the image exists.

Comment: actually i resolve the probleme by removing `Server.MapPath` i don't know why but it solve it thank you for your help .

Comment: Please post an answer containing your solution and come back to mark it as answer. In this way other people will also be able to benefit from your answer.